# How to download visual basic 2008

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I was tired of going to download visual studio. I need to download vb.net . i tried that. but i am confusion about vb.net, Asp.net and .net. Are they related to each other? what are the differences between them ?

Comment: Thank you so much. i get rid of my confusions.

Answer (score 1):

1) .NET is a framework, Vb.net is a programming language, ASP.net is a server side technology. And yes, they are related to each other.

2) Differences between them: 
http://www.rapidprogramming.com/questions-answers/What-is-the-difference-between-ASP-NET-and-VB-NET--719

Note: I got this from a quick google search (I do hope you tried to search for it).

BTW: Visual Studio 2008 is outdated and I highly doubt Microsoft offers it on their website any more. You can however try to search for "Visual Studio Express 2010 .iso download" or "Visual Studio Express 2008 .iso download" and maybe if you are lucky will find links to them.

Comment: Please do not condone to these questions they are off topic.

Comment: Alright. Thank you for that edit. @halfer

Comment: If my answer solved your problem @Mish, kindly consider marking it as the answer, so that any others with the same confusion can find the answer easily. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to get Visual Basic 2008!

Just get Visual studio. It supports multiple languages(Visual Basic, C# etc.) 
+ Visual Basic 2008 is outdated!